# Function definition interrupts pattern matching?

Tags: function-construction, symbolic, algebra

I'm trying to redefine NonCommutativeMultiply (NCM) to behave like an anticommuting operator, based on the [question here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161048/273). This involves calling Unprotect on NCM and adding a definition that leaves `a**b**c` as-is, but changes `a**c**b` to `-a**b**c`. The simplifications all work fine, but after doing all this MatchQ behaves a bit weirdly, returning False when I think it should return true. If I call `Block[{NonCommutativeMultiply},MatchQ[...]]` then the pattern does indeed match! This solution works, but I'd really like to know what's going on here. Why is my MatchQ returning False?

Minimal example:

```
(* Before adding the canonical ordering definition, this expression is matched *)
Print[MatchQ[NonCommutativeMultiply[s[1],s[2],s[3]],NonCommutativeMultiply[s[1],d___]]];
(* Out[] := True*)

(* Add a canonical ordering definition (leave a**z as a**z, but change z**a to -a**z) *)
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
ClearAttributes[NonCommutativeMultiply,Flat]
NonCommutativeMultiply[H___,B_,A_,T___]:=-NonCommutativeMultiply[H,A,B,T]/;Not[OrderedQ[{B,A}]]

(* After defining canonical ordering, the expression isn't matched any more! This is the problem line. *)
Print[MatchQ[NonCommutativeMultiply[s[1],s[2],s[3]],NonCommutativeMultiply[s[1],d___]]];
(* Out[] := False *)

(* Oddly enough, if s[1] is replaced with a simpler variable, we again match *)
Print[MatchQ[NonCommutativeMultiply[a,s[2],s[3]],NonCommutativeMultiply[a,d___]]];
(* Out[] := True *)

(* It can also be fixed with Block. *)
Print[Block[{NonCommutativeMultiply},MatchQ[NonCommutativeMultiply[s[1],s[2],s[3]],NonCommutativeMultiply[s[1],d___]]]];
(* Out[] := True *)
```

It should be noted that `s[1]**s[2]**s[3]` is not changed or reordered by the rule I've added.

Comment: The issue is that nothing stops your definition being applied when an object like `d___` appears in `NonCommutativeMultiply`.  You can combat this with [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a couple comments:

1. There is no need to use [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print).
2. There is no need to remove the [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat) attribute

Next, as @jjc385 comments, the problem is that your pattern evaluates:

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[s[1], d___]
```

> -d___ ** s[1]

Clearly, `NonCommutativeMultiply[s[1], s[2], s[3]]` will not match this pattern. To avoid this evaluation, you can use [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern):

```
MatchQ[
    NonCommutativeMultiply[s[1],s[2],s[3]],
    HoldPattern@NonCommutativeMultiply[s[1],d___]
]
```

> True

Note that I don't use [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print).

By the way, you might try the following alternative instead:

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[a__] /; !OrderedQ[{a}] := Signature[{a}] NonCommutativeMultiply @@ Sort[{a}]
```